# correct use of fgets?

Tags: c, fgets

In this program I am getting segmentation fault due to line:

```
fgets( string , 50, in );
```

If I comment it out the program exits fine but I am not sure what I am doing wrong with it?
I checked the declaration of function fgets which seems fine for the program.

```
//char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)


#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  FILE *in;
  char string[100];

  in = fopen("in.txt", "r" );

  // if i remove this line segmentation fault is no more.
  fgets( string , 50, in );  

  fclose(in);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about testing the result of `fopen()` before using `in`? It may be returning `NULL`.

Comment: You probably haven't created the file in.txt in your directory, fopen("in.txt","w+") would create a new file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fopen()` might not have been successful, check the return value of that before you try to read.

Comment: This is very likely to be the correct answer.  if fopen fails, you get a NULL pointer back, then the fgets tries to do an operation on a NULL pointer.  A gegmentation fault is a reasonable response to that sort of thing